# map table argument NULL xcode error when I click button in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null

I am using a UIButton to switch the text within the textbox on the screen shown in image 1. However I am getting this error when attempting to click the button through the iPhone simulator.

void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void * _Nullable): map table argument is NULL

[Image of xcode simulator & ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2odLj.jpg)

[Image of ViewController Scene and hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUhSh.png)

Have tried looking through Apple's xcode documentation and other sources but have found nothing.

Comment: On button tap you call a loop and set text for every person in the list, which doesn't make sense. It has the same effect as: biography.text = Persons.personList.last?.bio

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is Persons.personList is nil when you try to use it.

Comment: I had the problem with Xcode 13.2.1 (iOS 15.2 simulator). No more with Xcode 13.3.1 (iOS simulator 15.4).